# How to Match in a Strict Order Data that comes in a Random Order?

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm quite new to regular expressions and I have the following target string resource which can sometimes differ slightly. For example, the string might be:

```
<TITLE>SomeTitle</TITLE>
<ITEM1>Item 1 text</ITEM>
<ITEM2>Item 2 text</ITEM2>
<ITEM3>Item 3 text</ITEM3>
```

And the next time the resource is requested, it's output might be:

```
<ITEM1>Item 1 text</ITEM>
<ITEM2>Item 2 text</ITEM2>
<ITEM3>Item 3 text</ITEM3>
<TITLE>SomeTitle</TITLE>
```

I want to capture the data between the two tags in order of the first example, so that the match would always match "SomeTitle" first, followed by the items. So if the search string was the second example, I need an expression that can first match "SomeTitle" and then somehow "reset" the position of the match to start from the beginning so I can then match the items.

I can achieve this with two different pattern searches, but was wondering if there is a way to do this in a single search pattern? Perhaps using lookaheads/lookbehinds and conditionals?

Comment: Do you need to match things in a specific order or just rearrange the data to make sure `<TITLE>` is ***always*** first?

Comment: Use an HTML or XML parser instead.

Comment: Does this help? [`(.*?)(<TITLE>.*?<\/TITLE>)`](http://regex101.com/r/cK0jM5/1)

Comment: @Sam - I just needed to make sure title was first. It's the only tag the can sometimes move around. The Items will always be in the same order.

Comment: @Wallboy, you mean make sure the title was always the 1st captured match? If so, you can use basic regex for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Capture Groups inside Lookaheads

Use this:

```
(?s)(?=.*<TITLE>(.*?)</)(?=.*<ITEM1>(.*?)</)(?=.*<ITEM2>(.*?)</)(?=.*<ITEM3>(.*?)</)
```

Even when the tokens are in a random order, you can see them in the right order by examining Capture Groups 1, 2, 3 and 4.

For instance, in the [online regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/24), see how the input is in a random order, but **the capture groups in the right pane are in the right order.**

**PCRE: How to use in a programming language**

The PCRE library is used in several programming languages: for instance PHP, R, Delphi, and often C. Regardless of the language, the idea is the same: retrieve the capture groups.

As an example, here is how to do it in PHP:

```
$regex = '~(?s)(?=.*<TITLE>(.*?)</)(?=.*<ITEM1>(.*?)</)(?=.*<ITEM2>(.*?)</)(?=.*<ITEM3>(.*?)</)~';
if (preg_match($regex, $yourdata, $m)) {
    $title = $m[1];
    $item1 = $m[2];
    $item2 = $m[3];
    $item3 = $m[4];
    } 
else { // sorry, no match...
     }
```